# Random effect with 0 variance in GLMM

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, panel-data, glmm

In this study, subjects are measured continuously over the day via electrocardiography (ECG). During the day, certain trigger events occur randomly. Once all the data is collected, the trigger events are examined and everytime a trigger event occured, the ECG is used to check for the presence of a certain medical condition. This means, that the number of observations per subject are different. In total there are $n=2240$ observations and $m=42$ subjects. The number of observations per subject range from 13 to 216.

This study has already been analyzed and I'm trying to understand the results.

To analyze the data a logistic regression with random intercept was choosen. I will use `glmer` from `lme4` in `R` to reproduce the results. Here $Y$ is a binary 0/1 variable and $X1, \ldots, X3$ are covariates of interest and `id` is the subject indicator. If I fit a model with just one variable I get this:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: Y ~ X1 + (1 | id) 
   Data: data 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
1548.1535 1565.2962 -771.0768 1542.1535 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.02596  0.1611  
Number of obs: 2240, groups: id, 42

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.1235717  0.0756041 -28.088  < 2e-16 ***
X1           0.0007553  0.0001924   3.927 8.62e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr)
X1 -0.166
```

What we see is that the variance of the random subject effect is 0.026. It is small, but not equal to zero. If I add two more covariates, I get:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (1 | id) 
   Data: data 

      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance 
1514.2474 1542.8186 -752.1237 1504.2474 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 id     (Intercept) 1.021e-11 3.195e-06
Number of obs: 2240, groups: id, 42

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -2.1770583  0.0727357 -29.931  < 2e-16 ***
X1           0.0009218  0.0001914   4.816 1.46e-06 ***
X2          -0.3782134  0.0625888  -6.043 1.51e-09 ***
X3           0.0041024  0.0045297   0.906    0.365    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
   (Intr) X1     X2    
X1 -0.229              
X2  0.281 -0.131       
X3 -0.044  0.013  0.054
```

Now the variance it technically 0.

How would I explain this? My interpretation is that due to the added covariates, all the variation is accounted for and there is no more subject specific variation left. Is this reasonable?

Additional info about the covariates:
$X1$ and $X2$ are trigger specific measurements (length and intensity).Their value usually changes for different trigger events. Hence they are different for each measurement even for the same subject. $X3$ is the age of the subject.

Comment: Yes. Conditioning on the covariates, the remaining among-individual variability is consistent with a pure Bernoulli process with zero among-subject variance.